# Accidentally changed where my gems are being installed

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, bundler

When running bundler, I normally type:

```
bundle install
```

However, I accidentally added another string after this, turning into the likes of:

```
bundle install foobar
```

Now all my gems are being installed to `./foobar`.  Even if I try to run `bundle install` without the third param, my gems are installed to ./foobar again anyway.  I can't seem to find any help on addressing this anywhere, and I'm not sure if it's an effect of bundler, rvm, etc.

How do I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out and thought I'd share for anyone else running into this.  It created a config file within the current path under `.bundle/config`, which contained a line reading: `BUNDLE_PATH: foobar`.

To fix it, I just did:

```
rm -rf .bundle
```

Comment: Thanks, you've saved me from growing a few grey hairs